# Problem with video which does not go with the sound

Tags: video, audio, sync

Is there any solution to a video that does not sync with the sound. The sound seems to be advance than the video.

Comment: we need more information about what you're trying to do.  are you editing/encoding the video yourself or are you just trying to fix the sync during playback?  some video players like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can adjust the audio track sync in realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's some streaming site, and you're just watching videos, a dirty trick is open twice, and mute one, just start a bit later or sooner one of both, as needed.(but vlc feature mentioned above is preferrable)

Another "fast" trick, in case you are encoding not just watching, is in a video editor that allows handling audio track separately (ie: Sony Vegas Studio), just move this audio track as needed, with a bit of trial and error.

There are better ways, but these are sort of basic/simple.